# MySQL's LOWER() and PHP's mb_strtolower() return the same result?

Tags: php, mysql, string, utf-8, multibyte

In PHP there's a series of functions for strings containing multibyte characters.
I'm referring to this list here: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php

I need to know if the MySQL's [LOWER()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_lower) function is the equivalent of PHP's [mb_strtolower()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php) function.
I want to make sure the results of the two functions are identical.
I'm gonna use both functions with UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Yes, they will return the same result.

Comment: Be sure if you use the MySQL LOWER() function that you set the php client connection to utf8. php defaults to latin1. You can set utf8 with this `mysql_set_charset('utf8')` (note mysql_* functions are deprecated) `mysqli_set_charset('utf8')` or in de PDO dsn string "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=utf8" if you use a PHP version lower than 5.2.3 you need use a query `SET NAMES utf8` right after your database connection code

Comment: What `COLLATION` are you using in MySQL?

Comment: @RaymondNijland I'm using mysqli and UTF-8 exactly as you said.

Comment: @RickJames utf8_general_ci

Comment: Please provide a short sample text that gives you trouble; I'll experiment.

Comment: @RickJames no trouble yet. I have db records in all the languages you can think of, I've tested both functions and all returned the same result. I' ve posted the question to make sure I'm not doing something wrong.

Comment: MySQL 8.0 had a major rewrite of its handling of UTF-8; it may have broken something.  What version are you using?  Do you have a test suite?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they perform identical functions.

`mysql>SELECT LOWER('wOrD');
-> word`

`php>echo mb_strtolower('wOrD');
-> word`